# Как сделать так, чтобы в цикле файл назывался по-разному?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Поясняю: у меня есть необходимость в создании нескольких файлов, но в одном цикле.
И при этом названия всех файлов должны отличаться.

Должно выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
for i in range(16):
    with open(f'{i}.txt', 'w') as {i}_file:
        {i}_file.write('test')
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Для строго уникальных (в том числе в разных запусках программы) имен файлов ипользуйте `str(uuid.uuid1())`.  А зачем нужны отдельные переменные для каждого файла - непонятно, можно закрывать файл и использовать ту же переменную, еще лучше через `with`, чтобы сам закрылся. Ну или уж создайте `list` файлов.

Comment: Названия файлов в этом коде отличаются, а ``{i}_file`` это не название файла. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(16):
    with open(f'{i}.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать при помощи библиотеки `random`:

```
import random

# Количество символов в имени файла
filename_length = 10

# Строка символов для генерации имени файла
valid_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"


# Функция для генерации уникального названия файла
def generate_filename():
    return "".join(random.choice(valid_chars) for _ in range(filename_length))


for i in range(16):
    with open(f'{generate_filename()}.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('test')
```

Такой подход гарантирует с 99.8% вероятностью, что названия файлов не повторятся.

Comment: Можно чуть короче - `"".join(random.choices(valid_chars, k=filename_length))` А вот вероятнось гораздо лучше - не повторение 99.8% будет аж при 80 миллионах файлов, вряд ли столько встретится в реальной задаче :)